# Copy object functions and properties in new object by value not by reference - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to copy the functions and properties of an object into new object. The old object should not effect by changing made in new Object.

Here is the object definition:

```
  var Call = function() {
        this.number="123";
    }
    Call.prototype.function1 = function() {
         return this.number;
    }
    var callobj = new Call();
```

I can access function1 using `callobj.function1()`.

What I have tried to copy it:

**Javascript:**

```
var newcallobj = Object.assign({}, callobj);
```

In this case, i am not able to access function1 but i can access number property directly.

**JQUERY:**

```
var newObj = jQuery.extend(true, {}, callobj); OR 
var newObj = jQuery.extend({}, callobj);
```

In this case, i am able to access function1 and property but when i change number like that `newObj.number="222"`. It also change the value of original object.

I know that there is couple of other posts. But all is not working for me. Please let me know if i am doing any thing wrong?

**AFTER @gurvinder372 answer(I am updating question):**
After @gurvinder372 answer. It is working for first level of property but if it has another object like i show below and i change the value of property of another object. Then it is effecting on original object also.

```
var ABC = function(){
    this.number = "333";
}
var Call = function() {
    this.number="123";
    this.anotherobj = new ABC();
}
Call.prototype.function1 = function() {
     return this.number;
}
var callobj = new Call();
var newcallobj = Object.create(callobj);
newcallobj.anotherobj.number= "123";
console.log(newcallobj.anotherobj.number);
console.log(callobj.anotherobj.number);
```

Output of both is 123. @gurvinder372. can you check th above code ?

Comment: `Object.assign` only copies the enumerable properties of an object.

Comment: @gurvinder372. Yes. But i also want to copy function1. Please give me solution if you have any..

Comment: Have you tried newcallobj.prototype = new Call() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. By the help of @gurvinder372. The following solution is working for me.

```
var ABC = function(){
    this.number = "333";
}
var Call = function() {
    this.number="123";
    this.anotherobj = new ABC();
}
Call.prototype.function1 = function() {
     return this.number;
}
var callobj = new Call();
var newcallobj = Object.create(callobj);
newcallobj.anotherobj = Object.create(callobj.anotherobj);
newcallobj.anotherobj.number= "123";
console.log(newcallobj.anotherobj.number);
console.log(callobj.anotherobj.number);
```

Please let me know if there is any better solution other than this?

Answer (score 2):

`Object.assign` only copies the enumerable properties of an object.

Use `Object.create` instead of `Object.assign`

```
var newcallobj = Object.create(callobj);
```

```js
var Call = function() {
    this.number="123";
}
Call.prototype.function1 = function() {
     return this.number;
}
var callobj = new Call();
var newcallobj = Object.create(callobj);
console.log(newcallobj.function1());
```

Comment: it is copying but when i change the number value like this newcallobj.number = "123"... It is also change the number value of callobj.number.

Comment: I don't think so, I tried `newcallobj.number = "23434";
console.log(callobj.number);` output is still `123`

Comment: `Object.create()` accepts a `prototype`, not an instance. It should be `var newcallobj = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(callobj), Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(callobj));`

Comment: @gurvinder372. i just updated the question. At the end of question. I have posted the code for which i have issues. Can you please check.